# Pandas/Python Pulling end of month rows from dataframe into separate dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Currently I have a time series data frame as follows:

```
dfMain =

          Date  Portfolio Value
0   2016-07-01     1.000000e+06
1   2016-07-08     1.025168e+06
2   2016-07-15     1.028053e+06
3   2016-07-22     1.024184e+06
4   2016-07-29     1.022491e+06
5   2016-08-05     1.023241e+06
6   2016-08-12     1.030325e+06
7   2016-08-19     1.032742e+06
8   2016-08-26     1.032567e+06
9   2016-09-02     1.028614e+06
10  2016-09-09     9.930876e+05
11  2016-09-16     9.956875e+05
12  2016-09-23     1.010174e+06
13  2016-09-30     1.010388e+06
14  2016-10-07     1.004989e+06
15  2016-10-14     9.924929e+05
16  2016-10-21     9.969708e+05
17  2016-10-28     9.816373e+05
18  2016-11-04     9.563689e+05
19  2016-11-11     9.869579e+05
20  2016-11-18     9.936929e+05
21  2016-11-25     1.009625e+06
```

Given that the dataframe can be different (can't just pull specific rows from example) what would be the best way to pull the closest to the end of month dates from the dataframe? for example index 4 would be pulled because that is the closest to the end of month date.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group on the month number and find the last record:

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, errors='coerce')
df.groupby(df.Date.dt.month).last()

           Date  Portfolio Value
Date                            
7    2016-07-29        1022491.0
8    2016-08-26        1032567.0
9    2016-09-30        1010388.0
10   2016-10-28         981637.3
11   2016-11-25        1009625.0
```

If rows aren't sorted by Date, call `sort_values` first:

```
df.sort_values('Date').groupby(df.Date.dt.month).last()

           Date  Portfolio Value
Date                            
7    2016-07-29        1022491.0
8    2016-08-26        1032567.0
9    2016-09-30        1010388.0
10   2016-10-28         981637.3
11   2016-11-25        1009625.0
```

Should work in any case.

If you have dates spanning multiple years, better to groupby on the year-month:

```
df.sort_values('Date').groupby([df.Date.dt.year, df.Date.dt.month]).last()
```

Comment: this works great, however a problem I am facing currently is it stops at index 12, and does not go more (date range was from 2016-2018 but went in reverse and only did 2017-2018 year range). any ideas?

Comment: @lee.edward01 Added edit, should work for any case spanning multiple years too.

Answer (score 1):

You need to sort the dates and then find the last value for each group.

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
grp = df.sort_values('Date').groupby(df['Date'].dt.month)
pd.DataFrame([grp.get_group(x).iloc[-1] for x in grp.groups])
```

Output:

```
        Date    Portfolio Value
4   2016-07-29  1022491.0
8   2016-08-26  1032567.0
13  2016-09-30  1010388.0
17  2016-10-28  981637.3
21  2016-11-25  1009625.0
```